# One to one using JPA annotations Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm facing several problems setting up a One to one associations.

Can you help me set up the relationship using annotations for the following table.

```
Login -> (id, username, password)
Members -> (member_id, name, address)
```

Here member_id is same as id in login.

Comment: The [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association) provide examples on how to do this.

Comment: Why should you separate Login from Members? just add properties (username and password) to the Members class. No need to overcomplicate the DB layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the example that the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5617) provides:

```
@Entity
class MedicalHistory implements Serializable {
  @Id Integer id;

  @MapsId @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
  Person patient;
}

@Entity
class Person {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
}
```

Replace `Person` with `Login`, and `MedicalHistory` with `Member`, add the fields you need, and you have your answer.